# Demonstrating solutions to two functional equations

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, functional-equations

Find examples (the more the better) of functions $f: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{C}$ satisfying the relations

1. $f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y)$
2. $f(xy) = f(x)f(y)$

I have only

1. $f(x)= ax$
2. $f(x)= x^a$

This task is from algebra but I don't know why.

Comment: Try putting values in for x and y, eg $x=0$, $x=y$ etc

Comment: Now try f(xy) = f(x)+f(y) and f(x+y) = f(x)f(y).

Answer (score 1):

Answer.

In case a. it is easy to show that $f(n)=nf(1)$. Hence, the $f$ HAS TO BE of the form $f(n)=an$.

In case b. if $\{p_k\}_{k\in\mathbb N}$ are the prime numbers then 
$$
f(p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_k^{a_k})=f(p_1)^{a_1}\cdots f(p_k)^{a_k}.
$$
So if $f\not\equiv 0 $, then it is determined once it is ARBITRARILY defined in the primes and the value $f(-1)$ has to be equal to $\pm 1$.

Answer (score 0):

You have

$$
f(0+0)=f(0)+f(0) \implies f(0)=0
$$

Also using second condition, for any $y\in \mathbb{Z}$

$$
f(1 \cdot y)=f(1)f(y)
$$

Since $\mathbb{C}$ is an integral domain, this can only happen if $f(1)=1$, or $f(y)=0$ for all $y\in \mathbb{Z}$

Notice that $f(n)=f(1+1+\cdots+1)$ where $1$ occurs $n$ times, so what can you say about value of $f(n)$, given above values and condition $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$?

What can you then deduce about $f(-n)$ (note that $f(n-n)=f(0)=0$)

(Your exampple a) fails if $a\neq 0$ or $1$: $f(x)=ax\neq a^2x=f(1)f(x)$)